# How to install the the "speedtest_cli" module for the speedtest-cli command on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I had an idea to test the internet speed of my local library. Some downloads finish quickly and some don't. Plus, I feel better knowing how to do networking administration from the command line.

I found a few programs that can be used via command line to test internet speed. The programs I found, `speedtest-cli` and `wget`. I tried `speedtest-cli` first on ubuntu 15.10. It worked and I got a better idea of the internet speed of my local library. It was pretty slow. I wanted to use the same program on ubuntu 14.04. However, the program issued an error that the `speedtest_cli` module was not available.

```
/usr/local/bin$ speedtest-cli
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/speedtest-cli", line 7, in <module>
    from speedtest_cli import main
ImportError: No module named speedtest_cli
```

Is this module supplied with the `speedtest-cli`, if not, how do I install it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

From a command prompt install pip, the python specific package manager, then use pip to install speedtest_cli and all dependent modules.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install speedtest-cli
```

To run use the command `speedtest-cli`

Comment: I tried this and got no such file or directory., but when I used "sudo speedtest-cli" it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GetDeb repositories.

Add the repository by installing a deb package

```
cd
wget http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-speedtest-cli
```

After that, remove your downloaded `speedtest-cli`

```
sudo rm /use/local/bin/speedtest-cli
```

Now open a terminal and start via

```
speedtest-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me. Here's my solution.

If you install `speedtest-cli` with `pip`, you'll get 2 files : `speedtest` and `speedtest-cli`.
What you probably haven't noticed is other files downloaded in `/home/<user>/.local/lib/<python version>/site-packages/`

where :

- `<user>` is the username you are loggedin when doing the `pip` install
- `<python version>` the python version used (in my case, was python2.7)

Ths thing is when you change user, the speedtest.py is not present in the user directory.

There is 3 different ways to solve your issue :

1. Change user and install again. You can do something like :

   ```
   sudo userX pip install speedtest-cli
   ```
2. Copy file `speedtest.py` in right directory of the user you want to be able to user `speedtest-cli`
3. Install as root so any user can use `speedtest` :

   ```
   sudo su
   pip install speedtest-cli
   ```

As stated on this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117242/3223953), you might need to do it that way :

```
sudo su
cd ~
umask 022
pip install speedtest-cli
```